# Stop element underneath fixed overlay from scrolling with Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create an overlay that may contain its own scrollbar. The overlay should take up the full width and height of the screen, and scroll its own contents if they are longer than the page height.

My problem is I can't figure out how to stop the actual page from scrolling when the overlay scrolls. I want this to act like a Bootstrap modal.

Here is the fiddle with a code example: https://jsfiddle.net/r5jLcekb/

In the example, I'm using:

```
fixed bg-black bg-opacity-50 w-screen h-screen overflow-y-scroll
```

As you can see, the page scrolls it's contents, not just the overlay. I only want the contents within the overlay to scroll. Is this possible to do purely with tailwind?

Comment: If you pass to body over css the `position: fixed` or even `overflow: hidden` then will stop to scroll the background together with the layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `overscroll-auto` -- see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overscroll-behavior for more.

Comment: This doesn't stop the parent element from scrolling, you can add `overscroll-contain` instead (in combination with overflow), which has the desired effect. ☺️

Answer (score 1):

The way I approached this problem is by adding a class to the body whenever this overlay is rendered. Whenever your overlay element is mounted you need to execute a javascript code that does the following :

```
  document.body.classList.add(`overflow-hidden`);
    document.body.style.marginRight =
      document.body.offsetWidth - widthBefore + "px";
```

The second assignment is optional and it's added to get rid of layout shift when scrollbar shows and hides

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. My parent container was scrolling for the entire length of the site when the fullscreen overlay was active, but the content was not scrolling in the fullscreen overlay.  I added overflow-y-scroll and overscroll-y-none to the fixed container and it worked nicely. Hope this saves someone some time :) Thanks Jas (comment above) for the point to overscroll.

See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow
and https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overscroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overscroll-contain` in combination with `overflow-scroll`,`overflow-x-scroll`, or `overflow-y-scroll`, which blocks the parent from scrolling at the same time.

**Ref:** https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overscroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Tailwind by:

- designating a class in your root styles file (e.g. `/styles/globals.css`) to remove overflow from `:root`
- conditionally apply that class to whatever overlay you're using, when it's open

For example, in my NextJS project, I added:

```css
 :root:has(.no-doc-scroll) {
    overflow:hidden;
  }
```

to `/styles/globals.css` and then I added this class to my full screen overlay with:

```js
{isOpen && (<div className={"h-screen w-screen fixed top-0 left-0 z-50 no-doc-scroll"}>
...
)}
```

DaisyUI does this for their modals.

Comment: but how do you do it using Tailwind?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SantiagoV. I added the implied part about added the class to your modal component and generally fleshed out the answer! Ty.